# How to put Desktop on External Drive/Non-System Partition?

Tags: desktop, symlink, alias, exfat, multi-boot

Is it possible to get something like a symbolic link/alias to direct to another folder on an external hard drive and still have the files display on the desktop?

I used:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Desktop
sudo ln -s /Volumes/<partition_label>/Desktop ~/Desktop
```

But the Desktop is just blank, and when I drag files onto the Desktop, they disappear and are copied to `/Volumes/<partition_label>/Desktop`

I recently tried replacing the Desktop with an alias instead, but I now only get a cancel icon popping up next to the cursor when I drag a file over it.  The partition is exFat so it's compatible with my tri-boot. I'm doing this so files are automatically available on each Desktop.

Any ideas to get this working?

I was also thinking about an alternative, something that automatically moved a file to `/Volumes/<partition_label>/Desktop/<file_name>` when it was dragged to `~/Desktop` and replaced with a symbolic link or alias on `~/Desktop`.  Is that a viable alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, using bindfs, I believe you need to install [OSXFUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io/):

1. `brew install bindfs` (if you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed - easy way) (or you can build it from [source](http://bindfs.org/) - slightly harder)
2. `cp -R ~/Desktop/  /Volumes/<partition_label>/Desktop/` To move all files from your local Desktop to the partition's Desktop folder.
3. `rm -rf ~/Desktop && mkdir ~/Desktop` Will delete and create new Desktop folder.
4. `bindfs /Volumes/<partition_label>/Desktop ~/Desktop` Mounts the Desktop folder on the partition to your Desktop folder.

Note that with this method, all items that are dragged from your system partition to the Desktop are copied-not moved-and that if you delete any files from within the mounted file system, they are not sent to the trash, rather they are permanently deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a folder hard link using coreutils. Remove the symlink you created and install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) if you don't already have it, then `brew install coreutils` and use:

```
sudo gln /Volumes/<partition_label>/Desktop ~/Desktop
```

(Be careful with removing hard links, since the destination will be deleted if you delete normally. To delete a hard link, use `unlink ~/Desktop`.)

Comment: I just tried that and got: `gln: /Volumes/<partition_label>/Desktop: hard link not allowed for directory`